# tableView's cell to fit image (vertical or/and horizontal)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, layout, cell

I use PFQueryTableViewController to download photos from Parse.com. As the uploaded images are from different devices (iphone 5, iPhone 6, iPhone  6 plus,...) and are of different aspects (horizontal or vertical) i've faced an issue of how to make them all fit in the tableView cell. I know that it is possible to crop photos before they are uploaded (like instagram) but i'd love to save their original size and aspect seeing that it is possible and is used in some apps.So I want to know your advices about:

1) what shall I use to display image (cell's background or imageView) ?,

2) how to make cell fit the image? Now i have it like that [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUnfd.jpg) even with left margin (no idea why it is applied to imageView, not to the label?).

Comment: use image view that fits the cell and aspect fit the image!!! You might need to add constraints for the imageviwew

Comment: How to make Row height dynamic in this case? Because it all depends on it. When i set it on 250 it looks like in the question's screenshot, when i change it to 500 vertical images almost fit in the row, but the horisontal are half-image out of the screen. I've added all the constraints to the imageView (0,0,0,0), but it doesn't affect the row's height. As i know there are 2 places where row's height is set: Size Inspector of tableView and Size Inspector of the cell. Also there is a Mode of the ContentView of the cell, but it doesn't solve my problem neither.